# jQuery find() works in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm setting up custom textExtraction for the jQuery plugin tablesorter control (which is probably irrelevant) and the sort works in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox. Here's a snippet of the JavaScript code:

```
    var searchResultsTables = $("table.FilterClass");

    searchResultsTables.tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        widgetZebra: { css: ["Odd", "Even"] },
        headers:
        {
            3: { textExtraction: function (node)
            {
                return $(node).find("img").length;
            }
            },
            4: { sorter: false }
        }
    }
    );
```

Node is the `<td>` (I believe). Some cells have an image in them and others don't. So, basically, this column should sort based on 0/1. All the other columns sort just fine (with the exception of the 5th column, which, as you can see, is set not to be sortable).

Here is a bit of the html upon which the sort is acting (2 rows):

```
<table class="SearchResultsTable FilterClass tablesorter">
    <tr class="Odd">
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder NameCell">
        <a href="/Candidate/2">Bill Clinton</a></td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder PartyCell">Democrat</td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder DistrictCell"></td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder IncumbentCell">
            <img src="/Images/green_check_mark.gif" />
        </td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell PoliticalSpectrumIndexCell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Even">
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder NameCell">
        <a href="/Candidate/13">Newt Gingrich</a></td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder PartyCell" title="Party for Socialism and Liberation">Party for...</td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder DistrictCell"></td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell RightBrownBorder IncumbentCell"></td>
        <td class="SearchResultsCell PoliticalSpectrumIndexCell"></td>
    </tr>
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: That would work in any browser, if your assumption that "node" is a `<td>` element is correct.  Of course, it's hard to say what the problem might be without seeing more code or a more thorough description of the problem.

Comment: Is this the exact code?  Including the `3:`?

Comment: but what if you have 2 or more `img` in the `td`... That would return `2`, instead of a `0` or `1`

Comment: If only you'd posted some html to go along with it. Or a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), demo to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the count (i.e., length) is. If it's accurate, the column should sort on it just fine. I'll post more code.

Comment: Are there any error messages of note in the JS console?

Comment: @birdus: try adding `id` to your table e.g. `SearchResultsTable` then have only this: `$(document).ready(function() { $("#SearchResultsTable").tablesorter(); } );` - any luck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can put a textextraction function within the header option.

When I coded an example like yours, I had this, and it worked:

```
 var searchResultsTables = $("table.FilterClass");        

 searchResultsTables.tablesorter({          
    widgets: ['zebra'],          
    widgetZebra: { css: ["Odd", "Even"] }, 
    textExtraction: function (node)              
        {    
            if (node.cellIndex == 3)
            {
                return $(node).find("img").length;   
            }
            else
            {
                return node.innerHTML
            }           
        }   
    headers:          
    {                           
        4: { sorter: false }   
    }     
} );
```